# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Tags: google-maps, mapkit, swift4

I am using google maps. I have latitude and longitude given. I need to show location on maps using coordinates. But I get error as :

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
And it prints the else part as: "Can't use comgooglemaps://"

In info.plist I have added : 
1. LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
    Item 0   String     googlechromes
    Item 1   String     comgooglemaps

2. Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

My code is given :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {  

  var data7: String?
  var data8: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     getAddress()
    }

  func getAddress() {

    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(data7),\(data8)&directionsmode=driving")!)
    }
    else {

      print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    }
}
```

Comment: why downvote ? i didn't get the solution on searching ?

Answer (score 1):

Run your app on a physical device (**NOT Simulator**) that does have the google maps app and it should launch correctly using your code.